# How works tcp/ip package transport inside Linux OS?

Tags: linux, tcpip

How works tcp/ip package transport inside Linux OS?

Comment: Homework question?

Comment: No. Just want to know kernel and NIC intercommunion.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're looking for that specific information? A problem?

Comment: Optimization application and OS. Application is not popular.

Comment: Read the source.  Or read [Understanding the Linux Kernel](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596005658) for exhaustive details about the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[These](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131777203) [might](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596102488) [help](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596002556).

Answer (score 2):

I found [this howto](http://www.tenouk.com/Module42.html), maybe it can help you.